# Unable to to access Generic Views with JWT authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, authentication, jwt

I'm at a loss - I have a django backend and react frontend.  On the frontend, I have a login page that sets a JWT token, and I use that token to query data from the django backend.  This all works perfectly.

But I also have direct views to these APIs via something simple as *http://localhost:8000/tables/data* which will just show me a default django view of these tables (ie: a paginated "select * from data" call) ... and hooked in through a `genericListAPIView`.

Now, as I said, everything works fine when feeding it via a curl command (or postman, or whatnot).  I get the JWT token, set it the Authorization access in the subsequent call to the API, and get the data back and do something with in in React.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to hoo that same JWT token when calling trying to access the generic view.  When I browse to it, I get

```
HTTP 401 Unauthorized
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"

{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

Which I guess make sense since I'm not going through any React authentication.  Yet, it's the same server.  Should be same authentication (and in fact the login accounts are being managed by django).

I've googled, and read (and tried) a bunch of different things and can't seem to wrap my head around what I am doing wrong.  Any help, or any direction, would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit lost with what is your exact problem. Can you more clearly say how you are making the failing request? Do you call it from curl with the Authorization header? Do you navigate to the generic view from a browser?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- I am navigating to the generic view from a browser.  Using curl (or even my react app) I can properly set the Authorization token, and hence get to call the API.  but I don't know how the generic view can inject the token when coming directly from the browser.

Comment: Ok, so that solves the mystery. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request from a browser, you can only rely on session cookies. The browser is not able to automatically add an access token to the request. In order to make a request with an access token, you have to make it using Javascript.

Comment: Yes, that's somewhat what I thought.  Though I've read session cookies are inherently insecure.  But for what I am doing, that doesn't bother me (at this time).  And while I can set the cookies when logging in initially, I can't seem to figure out how to, on the backend (in django, which is python) get access to those cookies to deconstruct and use to authenticate access to any specific views.

Comment: I don't know where you read that cookies are insecure. In my opinion they are safer than using tokens in the browser. Handling cookies In django shouldn't be a problem. There should be a ton of tutorials showing how to do that. There are probably some methods on the request that let you read them or you could just parse the cookies header.

Comment: XSS?  CSRF?  Aren't those due to cookies being insecure?  Admittedly I don't know enough about this so perhaps I am not reading it correctly.  Of course, session cookies are probably very secure.  And this app I'm writing is only available behind a VPN anyhow so I'm not too worried.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: XSS has nothing to do with cookies. CSRF exploits cookies, but this does mean they are insecure. There are well-established methods to protect against CSRF. It's also important how you configure cookies. HTTP only, secure, same site cookies are pretty well protected from many threats.